# How can I create a custom tweening function to randomize mouse movements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I'm currently experimenting with pyautogui and am trying to randomize my program's actions as much as possible to mimic human inputs.

Right now, i'm using a built-in tweening function for the mouse movements as such :

```
pyautogui.moveTo(x, y, duration=2, tween=pyautogui.easeInOutQuad)
```

That works as expected, but the mouse is still doing a straight line to the destination point. I want to know if there's a way to code my own tweening function to randomize the mouse movements. The documentation is very evasive on that point and i can't seem to find any examples.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The tweening functions come from `pytweening`,, and are simple `def blah(n): return new number based on n` with the input being a number [between 0 and 1](https://github.com/asweigart/pytweening/blob/master/pytweening/__init__.py). Writing your own should be really easy.

Comment: Thanks for the link ! If I understood correctly the tweening functions can only be used for a linear movement and are only acting on the speed of the pointer. That's not really what I'm trying to do so I might have to look somewhere else.

Comment: No? The input is linear from 0 to 1, but the output can be "whatever you want" as long as it starts at 0 and ends at 1. What it does in between those two end points is _entirely_ up to you =)